# PHPStorm find and replace complete <head> tag in all the project files

Tags: html, search, replace, phpstorm, head

I have got a bunch of HTML files from a client in a project.
All the html pages have the same header and footer div,
I have modified the header in the homepage index.html file. I want this modifed header to be replaced in all the html files in the project folder.

How do I use phpstorm search and replace in all files to replace the whole   with the one I modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mac,

CMD + SHIFT + R

Then you'll see the small page below.

[image]

If there are lots of records, it may take a while to find all of them, though.

Comment: I know about this, but how do I search for a complete starting and ending tag like I want to replace head tag with all it's contents <head> .... </head> in all project files. Right now I can only search for strings but how do I tell phpstorm to replace the complete head tag in all files

Comment: I have no idea. I looked for but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: I finally wrote a regex that allowed me to match my exact starting and closing head tag.

Comment: It's great to hear. When you find an answer to your question and if there isn't any answer posted yet, it is highly recommended answering your own question on StackOverflow. Just my two cents. :)